# ngrx/effects - Actions that are depedent on other actions

Tags: angular, ngrx

When fetching data from an API, I first need to check if I already have a token stored, and if it is still valid. If not, I need to get a new one from the API and wait for the `GET_TOKEN_SUCCESS` action before I can make the actual data request.

How do I handle this scenario with `ngrx/effects` without having to write all the logic in one single effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to emit the action that gets the token and then re-emit the effect's action when a token is received. You could do something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {

    private _tokens: Observable<TokenState>;

    // Inject the store so that the token can be selected and validated in any
    // effects.

    constructor(private _actions_ Actions, private _appStore: Store<AppState>) {
        this._tokens = this.appStore_.select<TokenState>("token");
    }

    @Effect()
    createUser = this._actions
        .ofType("CREATE_USER_REQUEST")

        // Combine the action with the latest token from the app state.

        .withLatestFrom(this._tokens, (action, token) => [action, token])
        .switchMap(([action, token]) => {

            if (isValidToken(token)) {

                // If the token is valid, perform the effect. For example,
                // this uses a promise-based service:

                return Observable
                    .fromPromise(this._userService.createUser(token, action.payload))
                    .map((user) => ({
                        type: "CREATE_USER_SUCCESS",
                        payload: user
                    })
                    .catch((error) => Observable.of({
                        type: "CREATE_USER_ERROR",
                        payload: error
                    }));

            } else {

                // If the token is invalid, emit a series of observables.
                // The first emits the action to get the token and the
                // second re-emits the original action after the token has
                // been successfully received.

                return Observable.concat(
                    Observable.of({ type: "GET_TOKEN_REQUEST" }),
                    this._actions.ofType("GET_TOKEN_SUCCESS").first().map(() => action)
                );
            }
        });
}
```

You could DRY this up using a function (that's passed the action, the token and the observable for the effect's behaviour - i.e. the observable with the service call in the above example) to perform the token validation and observable concatenation, as there's nothing in there that's effect-specific.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! can you please explain `this._actions.ofType("GET_TOKEN_SUCCESS").first().map(() => action)` a bit more? I can't get that part to work. It never "catches" the `GET_TOKEN_SUCCESS` action. It also seems that I can't use `Observable.concatMap`, only `observable1.concatMap(() => ...)`, but I guess that shouldn't make any difference

Comment: My use of `concatMap` was incorrect, as it's an operator rather than an observable creator. I've updated the answer. The intention was to emit observables that are flattened into the action stream, with the second re-emitting the original event when the getting of the token succeeds. If the answer is still broken, I will review it tomorrow - my time - as I'm pretty much toast, now.

Comment: Managed to solve it by changing `.concatMap((o) => o);` to `.concatMap(o => Observable.of(o));`. I edited the answer to reflect this. Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Finally got around to looking at this. The `concatMap` call is not required.